# seeding mode in SQL Server 2019

Tags: availability-groups, sql-server-2019, trace-flags

Does activating the TF9567 seeding mode trace flag speed up the synchronization process in AlwaysOn?

I am using SQL Server 2019.

Comment: What do you exactly mean when you say ""speeds up sync process", so are you talking about seeding speed, if so, then yes it does.

Answer (score 2):

> Trace Flag 9567 : Enables compression of the data stream for Always On
> Availability Groups during automatic seeding. Compression can
> significantly reduce the transfer time during automatic seeding and
> will increase the load on the processor. For more information,
> see [Automatically initialize Always On availability](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/automatically-initialize-always-on-availability-group?view=sql-server-ver15) group and [Tune
> compression for availability group.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/tune-compression-for-availability-group?view=sql-server-ver15)

As the document says, just when automatic seeding process during. Synchronization doesn't relate to this trace flag.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the trace flag I have seen with 200GB db sync time was about 40 minutes vs 8+ hours without the trace flag!  That was going to a DR box in a different data center.